# How to use zend_debug:dump in Magento2

Tags: magento2, zend-framework, debug

Do we need to include the class  in the constructor?

In Magento 1, we simply use ***zend_debug::dump()->debug*** to debug object, how about for Magento 2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use simply following way:

```
\Zend_Debug::dump($someVar)
```

Comment: \Zend_Debug is not working in magento 2.3, so do you have any idea how to run \Zend_Debug::dump(); in magento 2.3 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also import `Zend_Debug` class at the top of your class file:

```
use Zend_Debug;
```

Then, your code will work as normal:

```
Zend_Debug($yourVar);
```

OR, you can directly instantiate the object of the class. For this, you don't need to import the class but have to use "backslash" infront of the `Zend_Debug` class name.

```
\Zend_Debug($yourVar);
```

**Reference:** PHP Documentation on [Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: in some class, i can use it, but sometimes it cant, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Zend_Debug gone from 2.3

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes/

Affected modules:

- Zend_Debug

Action: Affected modules and classes were removed.

Reason: They are no longer used in Magento or Marketplace extensions, are expensive and time-intensive to maintain, and can cause potential security risks if not maintained properly.

Comment: Thanks for the updates, seems v2.3 removed many Zend functions. Do you know what is another good function for outputing debug message? Just var_dump?

Comment: That was the Magento teams way of getting 2.3 php 7.2 compatible.  I used Zend_Debug all the time.  I've been using `echo <pre>; var_dump($var);`

Comment: I've given this more thought https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/283483/70343

Answer (score 0):

**In Magento 2.3+**

To use the `\Zend_Debug::dump($someVar)` method :

1. Create a folder `app/code/Zend`;
2. Create a file `app/code/Zend/Debug.php`
3. Copy in `Debug.php` :

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework
 *
 * LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the new BSD license that is bundled
 * with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@zend.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * @category   Zend
 * @package    Zend_Debug
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license    http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 * @version    $Id$
 */

/**
 * Concrete class for generating debug dumps related to the output source.
 *
 * @category   Zend
 * @package    Zend_Debug
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license    http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 */

class Zend_Debug
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected static $_sapi = null;

    /**
     * Get the current value of the debug output environment.
     * This defaults to the value of PHP_SAPI.
     *
     * @return string;
     */
    public static function getSapi()
    {
        if (self::$_sapi === null) {
            self::$_sapi = PHP_SAPI;
        }
        return self::$_sapi;
    }

    /**
     * Set the debug ouput environment.
     * Setting a value of null causes Zend_Debug to use PHP_SAPI.
     *
     * @param string $sapi
     * @return void;
     */
    public static function setSapi($sapi)
    {
        self::$_sapi = $sapi;
    }

    /**
     * Debug helper function.  This is a wrapper for var_dump() that adds
     * the <pre /> tags, cleans up newlines and indents, and runs
     * htmlentities() before output.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $var   The variable to dump.
     * @param  string $label OPTIONAL Label to prepend to output.
     * @param  bool   $echo  OPTIONAL Echo output if true.
     * @return string
     */
    public static function dump($var, $label=null, $echo=true)
    {
        // format the label
        $label = ($label===null) ? '' : rtrim($label) . ' ';

        // var_dump the variable into a buffer and keep the output
        ob_start();
        var_dump($var);
        $output = ob_get_clean();

        // neaten the newlines and indents
        $output = preg_replace("/\]\=\>\n(\s+)/m", "] => ", $output);
        if (self::getSapi() == 'cli') {
            $output = PHP_EOL . $label
                . PHP_EOL . $output
                . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            if(!extension_loaded('xdebug')) {
                $flags = ENT_QUOTES;
                // PHP 5.4.0+
                if (defined('ENT_SUBSTITUTE')) {
                    $flags = ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE;
                }
                $output = htmlspecialchars($output, $flags);
            }

            $output = '<pre>'
                . $label
                . $output
                . '</pre>';
        }

        if ($echo) {
            echo($output);
        }
        return $output;
    }

}
```