# Use Zend_Debug in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2.3, zend-framework, debug

As Magento removed many Zend functions in v2.3, is there a way to use `Zend_Debug::dump()` by potentially manually installing the missing composer module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily no.  I suggest looking for an alternative.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/257545/70343

I've seen an implementation of Symfony var dump.

https://github.com/vdrahaniuk/magento2-dump-server

I might look at later actually.  Seems like a good idea.  But this should get your started.

composer require symfony/var-dumper": "^4.1.1"

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html

And go from there.

## Update

I had an experiment with it and yes it works really well.

Go here to see my experiment and outcome

https://github.com/DominicWatts/MagentoDump

[image: Demo screen]

Answer (score 0):

So far I found a quickest workaround:

`echo '<pre>'; var_dump($data);`

Comment: Generally that's what I use if I'm in a hurry. However you have to be cautious of what you dump.  Try using that on a product object and you will crash the browser.